# Is there a pattern to trigger user-defined alert based on certain criteria?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, esper

We need to allow our users to set alerts and be notified when certain objects are created or updated with certain criteria (e.g. category is in a list, amount is greater than X...).

I've thought about 2 ways of doing this:

- use the observer pattern on create and update to evaluate all of the rules against this object to see if they are triggered (this will probably have to be queued)
- run a background task that will run all rules against all objects on a periodical basis

The former seems more "real time-ish" but if we create 2 objects per second, then we'll evaluate the rules quite a lot.
The latter would be a bit more efficient in that regard.

Both ways seem intensive (we expect ~500 rules and 10-20 000 objects) and I wanted to know if there was a more efficient way... or a right way.

Real time evaluation of the rules is a nice to have, but not mandatory, we could run a task every 6 hours.

I've seen Esper for Java and .net but this doesn't look like an option for Ruby (+ this seems a bit overkill and I would avoid adding dependencies if possible).

We have a Rails 4.1 application running ruby 2.0

Comment: Why not a combination: A observer that generates a background job (DelayedJobs, Sidekiq). That background job can start immediately (depending on your queue length), but does not slow down the web request.

Comment: There is no "evaluate all rules" in Esper because its not a request-response rule engine. Esper is a continuous query engine - design your events and your continuous queries such that they fire when an event arrives that fulfills the pattern or triggers the threshold. I'd recommend checking the "solution patterns" page that is linked from the top page.